# NextAuth expression is not callable error

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

So I was learning authentication in Next.js using next-auth. I followed the documentation and here is my `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` code

```js
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
    }),

    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Username",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "John Smith",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "*******",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // here data should come from the database
        const user = { id: "1", name: "John", password: "pass" };
        if (
          credentials?.username === user.name &&
          credentials.password === user.password
        ) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
};
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I am getting an error in this file that says

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("e:/Javascript/learnauth2/node_modules/next-auth/next")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

The version of `next-auth` I have is `4.22.2` and that of `next` is `13.4.10`

Any help regarding this is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So I guess I found a solution to this issue. I tried `npm update` and boom! There were no errors. No idea what the main issue was